# How to change the vsync interval in GPUView

Tags: opengl, gpu, frame-rate, vsync

When click toggle vsync in GPUView, the interval seems to be default to 16.6ms (60Hz), even though my OpenGL app is running on 75Hz monitor at 75 fps. How can I change the vsync interval in GPUView?